# Receive an event on 'addPageAction' finish in New Relic Browser API

Tags: javascript, newrelic

I have this code:

```
newrelic.addPageAction(name, eventData);
```

Sometimes I need to post a page action when a link to an external page is clicked. I can manually trigger this page change, but I don't know when the pageAction is successfully send to NewRelic.

Is it possibly to listen to an event or a callback when this is successfully send?